# How to make JPA Pagination return Date instead of epoch when sorting by date?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, pagination

I'm working on a legacy project and I'll try to make it short. I have this `Entity` that has a field

```
private Date createdAt;
```

Then I've defined an implementation in my `JpaRepository` extension:

```
Page<Entity> findAllByUserId(Long userId, Pageable pageable);
```

And when invoking it, I do so:

```
Sort direction = order != null && order.equalsIgnoreCase("ASC")
      ? Sort.by("createdAt").ascending()
      : Sort.by("createdAt").descending();
PageRequest pageRequest = PageRequest.of(page - 1, size, direction);
```

So I'm basically sorting them by date. Problem is, if I don't do pagination, it will return the `Date` as `2019-10-09T04:17:49.000+00:00`. That's what I want because that's what everybody using it is expecting it to return. However, whenever I do use pagination, it returns the date as `epoch` time. I don't really have a problem with it myself, but this is a legacy application and a lot are depending on it so I'd want to change it back into the initial format.

Note: And yes, I know. Date is not recommended it's old I know. But this is a legacy project and I tried changing it to LocalDateTime and unfortunately I wasn't qualified enough as a pasta chef.

Comment: It will create a `java.util.Date` regardless of what you are showing. So the error is not in the query or page, but probably in the way you are showing the results.

Comment: You sending `Page<Entity>` as response ? Can you show how you are serializing the response ?

Comment: I'm just returning the `Page<Entity>` itself as is because they're making use of the other `Page` info

Comment: `java.util.Date` has legacy compatibility methods that are using an `Instant`: `Date.from(Instant instant)` and `Date.toInstant()`. Having such a `java.time.Instant` you can either format that to a `String` or convert it to a `ZonedDateTime` or an `OffsetDateTime`, which can then create a formatted `String` of their values.

Comment: So is it safe to assume that the cause is the usage of `java.util.Date`? And may this perhaps be resolved by migrating to `LocalDateTime`?